# Invalid arguments in method call

Tags: c++

In my class `InVal`, I have a method and a friend operator declared as below:

```
void Parse(std::istream& file) throw (int);
friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, const InVal& id3);
```

The friend operator `>>` code is this:

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, const InVal& val) {
    val.Parse(is);
    return is;
}
```

On the line `val.Parse(is)` I'm getting `Invalid arguments` with candidate offer being `void Parse(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char>>&)`. In `iosfwd`, I have

```
typedef basic_istream<char>         istream
```

So somewhere something isn't matching.  Why am I getting the error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val` is a `const` reference, which means that you can only call `const` member functions on it. You need to declare `Parse` as a `const` member function like so:

```
void Parse(std::istream& file) const throw (int);
```

This promises the compiler that `Parse` will not modify the `InVal` object it is being invoked on.

Comment: Ah! I keep getting bitten by this.

Comment: Maybe it's better to make the second argument of `operator >>` non const? I assume that in Parse method you load InVal's content somehow..

Comment: @PavelDavydov Yes, that's exactly what I did.  The `const` came in because I did copy-paste from `<<` operator, then changed `ostream` to `istream` but forgot to remove `const` from the second parameter.